# When using \cite, I don't see any of the book references in my Bibliography when using TexMaker

Tags: biblatex, citing

I tried looking for this online but no luck so far.  The only entries I see are all the articles I have in the bibliography.  Anyone mind helping with the proper command?

Some details...

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\newenvironment{equations}{\equation\aligned}{\endaligned\endequation}
```

and...

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{rsaCryptoBiblio}
```

also in the bibliography...I have...

@article and @book references

And two examples...

```
@article{Atkins1994, 
author = "Derek Atkins and Michael Graff and Arjen K. Lenstra and Paul C. Leyland",
title = "{T}he {M}agic {W}ords are {S}quemish {O}ssifrace",
year = "1994",}

@book{Intro2012,
author    = "Wade Trappe and Lawrence Washington",
title     = "Introduction to Cryptography with Coding Theory",
year      = "2002",
publisher = "Pearson",}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added what is in my tex but otherwise I'm not sure what else I would need to show.  I'm new to Latex and most of what I've accomplished has been through lots of searching.  All I want to do is to use \cite for books as well

Comment: Well, the most important stuff, your `rsaCryptoBiblio.bib` isn't there ;-)

Comment: Ok I added two examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the warning `missing journal` for the `Atkins1994` article everything seems to be ok. Following works out of the box if `bibtex` is used after compilation with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{rsaCryptoBiblio}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography file: `rsaCryptoBiblio.bib`

```
@article{Atkins1994, 
author = "Derek Atkins and Michael Graff and Arjen K. Lenstra and Paul C. Leyland",
title = "{T}he {M}agic {W}ords are {S}quemish {O}ssifrace",
journal="Silly walk Journal",
year = "1994"
}

@book{Intro2012,
author    = "Wade Trappe and Lawrence Washington",
title     = "Introduction to Cryptography with Coding Theory",
year      = "2002",
publisher = "Pearson"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear.  I have the references in my bibliography.  What I can't do is actually cite them in the body of my paper.  When I use the command \cite, I only see what I have in articles.  The books do not appear.

Comment: @AndyD: Makes no difference. If use `\cite{Intro2012}` I will see the book in the references, if I use `\cite{Atkins1994}`, I will see the article reference

Comment: doh.  I was letting TexMaker confuse me by not showing the book in the autofill.  I didn't even try.  Appreciate the help and apologize for wasting your time

Comment: @AndyD: It wasn't waste of time for me... your problem is solved, although differently as thought! Happy TeXing!

Comment: @AndyD: No problem. Till next time ...